# Asynchronous event triggers in a distributed system? (java)

Tags: java, asynchronous, netty, zeromq, distributed-system

I am implementing a distributed system that runs a consensus protocol. The algorithm that I am using does not matter for my question. What I am concerned with is the communication between nodes in the system. I need a way to allow for asynchronous messaging between nodes. There are certain types of messages that should trigger an event in listening nodes. For example

```
(node_1) sendMessageA()              ---> (node_2, ..., node_n) recvMessageA()
(node_2, ..., node_n) sendMessageB() ---> (node_1) recvMessageB()
(node_1) sendMessageC()              ---> (node_2, ..., node_n) recvMessageC()
...
```

Basically, I have a function that might be called from a given node_i, and this should send a message to the other nodes in the system and trigger the appropriate function in the other nodes. These messages need to be asynchronous in this distributed system.

**What are some good frameworks or tools to help allow for this type of communication?**

I am aware of [Netty](http://netty.io/index.html), and [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/), which both seem relevant for this type of problem, but I don't have experience with either. **Which one of these is better suited to this type of problem?** Are there any better alternatives? I would prefer a framework that uses java, but I would consider technologies that use other languages as well.

Comment: Using RMI you can communicate between peers in plain java. If you stick to java and want to avoid the complexity of a second framework I would suggest to use this.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you looking into [JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/). It is a Java based group communication toolkit. If you looking into the docs, you will see that you can add the required functionality by implementing the Protocol interface. It takes a bit to get used to it, but the documentation is excellent. Also, the [community](http://jgroups.1086181.n5.nabble.com/) is quite large: you should be able to find help easily if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I decided to use was [Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/). Even though I didn't use it for cross-language communication, it was still very helpful because it allowed me to create a simple definition of the interface that I wanted to use between nodes, and then it auto-generated the appropriate classes. To quote their site:

> Instead of writing a load of boilerplate code to serialize and transport your objects and invoke remote methods, you can get right down to business.

This was definitely true, and after a few hours of learning how Thrift works, I was able to set up communication with RPCs.